# My project won't build because "'XXX' is declared but its value is never read"

Tags: reactjs, npm

A few days ago, my project built fine. Then I made some changes, stashed them, and suddenly it doesn't want to build because of messages like "'React' is declared but its value is never read." I created an .env file and added "CI=false", but that didn't seem to help.

[image]

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and I'd rather not change too many files if I can help it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That is probably a warning, check the logs for errors.

Comment: In addition to messages, you also get told in which files and on what line, so: open those files, on those lines, and fix the problem?

Comment: Your eslint file is strict, try `next build --no-lint`

Comment: next : The term 'next' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: "*I'm trying to follow a tutorial*" - you'll need to tell us at least **which** tutorial you are following, and which command you are running that returns the error. Also please [post the error message as text, not a link to a painting of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include it as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Answer (score -1):

I was about 4 1/2 hours into [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_W3R2VwRyF4&list=PL6QREj8te1P6wX9m5KnicnDVEucbOPsqR). Apparently, I should have using `npm run dev` (*vite*) instead of `npm run build` (*tsc && vite build*). Thanks for your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).